# Test Automation Orchestration Tool / Language

Tags: automated-tests, orchestration

The test harness for this scenario involves: (on ubuntu)

1. Monitoring and reporting some pre-conditions like database tables, daemons running etc.
2. Run scripts to inject data to mysql. This scripts insert small amount of data, and need to be run N times based on some FINISH Criteria
3. Monitor some tables and create graphs results for the same

Then, we can run this test with various sets of data, and see the results.

This sort of workflow is common to many testing use cases. Is there a tool that already provides this orchestration, this is ALL command Line based environment.

I searched but could not find any such tool for Test Orchestration.

Now i can develop it myself in Java or Perl , or any other language, but its would be nice to see if there is something already available, so i dont have to start from scratch.

Now [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) does provide a kind of test orchestration, but is like having a command line tool on steroids, and again the test results need to be integrated with Jenkins plugins and tools available.
I am wondering if there are java libraries, or perl packages available, which have event driven / result driven Orchestration

I have also included "Language" Since i wanted to know if there is a best suited language in which to develop this framework , since there are SO many languages to chose from. At the same time, is it a good idea to choose (Lets say) Java to develop this Test Orchestration Framework if the AUT ( Application Under Test ) was developed in Perl ?

I realize this is a two part question, and can be taken as two separate questions, but i did not want to loose the THEME here.

As far as Deployment Orchestration, there are many choices like [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/), [Kokki](http://samuelks.com/kokki/), [Poni](http://melor.github.com/poni/), [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) etc, but none for Test Orchestration.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you exactly mean for *orchestration*. If you mean controlling a system made up by several components you may use tools like [Robot Framework](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/) or [Cucumber](http://cukes.info).